# How to use bold, regular and italic font styles for custom fonts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts

I am currently using the font Yoxall in my app, and have .ttf files for "Regular", "Bold", and "Italic". I am currently using the coke `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Yoxall" size:20.0f]` to set the font as the regular Yoxall, using the YOXALL__.ttf file in my supporting files. I would also like to use italic Yoxall elsewhere in my app, but I obviously cannot call the same method, as "Yoxall" refers to both these files.

What code would I use to distinguish between the regular, bold, and italic styles of this font?

Comment: Add all required font files in your projects and mention name of those file in .plist file

Comment: keyur, is there some sort of tutorial online for what you're describing? I don't know how doing this would help me at present. Thanks

Comment: if you have added all files in your projects then it will giving all fonts name in nslog from there you can search appropriate name font which you can use in [UIFont fontWithName:@"Yoxall" size:20.0f] this method

Comment: This works. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
 for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]){
        NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
     }
 }
```

This function will give all fonts name.

Comment: To anyone seeing this: This only worked after listing my fonts in the info.plist file. You can look up tutorials on how to do that online :)

Comment: yes you have to mention that font file name in plist file and also put that in your project as well

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer: "How to use bold, regular and italic font styles for custom fonts?" This will just show all fonts available.. How is possible to use a bold and italic in same phrase, for example? or even just all in bold, ou half in bold and another half in italic?

Answer (score 0):

> Use **+[UIFont familyNames]** to list of all font family names known
>   to the system, you can use +[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:] to list
>   all of the font names known to the system.

```
Example code:

static void dumpAllFonts() {
    for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
        for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
        }
    }
}
```

in output you can get font name. hope it's help