# How do i add in a custom font into my iOS app?

Tags: ios, fonts, ios9

Before Xcode updated to v7, there used to be a font which i used for my app called Heiti SC. After the update the font just disappeared. Now I have to figure out where i can download this font and how i can put it into my app. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Follow this steps http://stackoverflow.com/a/24708424/2594560

Comment: add custom font file in your project.Then you have to find font name that you need to mention in method. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491034/how-to-use-bold-regular-and-italic-font-styles-for-custom-fonts/31491067#31491067

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here you can download the font
http://www.free-fonts.com/heiti-tc-light..
After downloading add the folder(.ttf format) to supporting files in the project.
Then Edit info.Plist like this

Fonts provided by Application take as array

Item 0 as Heiti SC.ttf

now you can set
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti SC" size:15];

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In addition to the answers that have already been given here:
(check this link [how to add custom font ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376941/how-to-use-custom-fonts-in-iphone-sdk))

Check the buildphase if the font has been added correctly. If you don't see your font here, just drag and drop it inside.